# How to get YARN "Memory Total" and "VCores Total" metrics programmatically in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm lingering around this: 
https://docs.actian.com/vectorhadoop/5.0/index.html#page/User/YARN_Configuration_Settings.htm

but none of those configs are what I need.

"yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb" was promising, but it's only for the node manager it seems and only gets master's mem and cpu, not the cluster's.

```
int(hl.spark_context()._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access those metrics from Yarn History Server.
URL: `http://rm-http-address:port/ws/v1/cluster/metrics`
metrics:

```
totalMB
totalVirtualCores
```

Example response (can be also XML):

```
{  "clusterMetrics":   {
    "appsSubmitted":0,
    "appsCompleted":0,
    "appsPending":0,
    "appsRunning":0,
    "appsFailed":0,
    "appsKilled":0,
    "reservedMB":0,
    "availableMB":17408,
    "allocatedMB":0,
    "reservedVirtualCores":0,
    "availableVirtualCores":7,
    "allocatedVirtualCores":1,
    "containersAllocated":0,
    "containersReserved":0,
    "containersPending":0,
    "totalMB":17408,
    "totalVirtualCores":8,
    "totalNodes":1,
    "lostNodes":0,
    "unhealthyNodes":0,
    "decommissioningNodes":0,
    "decommissionedNodes":0,
    "rebootedNodes":0,
    "activeNodes":1,
    "shutdownNodes":0   } }
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Metrics_API

All you need is to figure out your Yarn History Server address and port- check in your configuration files, can't help you with this since I don't know where do you manage Yarn.

When you have the URL, access it with python:

```
import requests
url = 'http://rm-http-address:port/ws/v1/cluster/metrics'
reponse = requests.get(url)
# Parse the reponse json/xml and get the relevant metrics...
```

Of course no Hadoop or Spark Context is needed in this solution

Comment: awesooomee. testing it now.